# Modify jQuery .prop();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is any way to modify jQuery `.prop()` function? Now I'm using `.trigger()` but I's problematic for me because I have to use It in many places. Is any way to create something like global callback function to make It automatically?
My code now:

```
objCheckAll.prop('checked', true).trigger('pseudoInput.refresh');
```

I want to fire this event always when I'll use `.prop('checked)` like global behaviour.

Comment: Yes, you could monkey patch it.

Comment: Create your own jQuery plugin method that does both `objCheckAll.checkAndTrigger()`

Comment: Fire an event when you read the property?

Comment: @jfriend00 It will be really hard to do because I'm using it in many places and replacing everything will take me ages

Comment: He means essentially just make a separate function called for example "checkAndTrigger()" that first calls .prop('checked', true) and triggers your refresh. Then just replace all calls of .prop() in your code with .checkAndTrigger().

Comment: @DasBeasto and what he's saying is that would be a lot of work because of all the replacing. (granted, there are tools that would make that find/replace easy)

Comment: @Wado What text editor are you using? Most have a find and replace all function... takes like, 2 seconds

Comment: You could also just use find/replace in most coding environments find: ".prop" replace: ".checkAndTrigger"

EDIT: beat me^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just overwrite jQuery's prop with your own

```
var oldProp = $.fn.prop;

$.fn.prop = function() {
    oldProp.apply(this, arguments);
    if (arguments[0] == 'checked') this.trigger('pseudoInput.refresh');
}
```

That would always call the trigger when `prop('checked')` is used

Comment: To the OP.  Personally, I think this a horrible idea and a bad practice.  Much better to make a new function that carries out both operations which I've put into my own answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I actually agree with that, and when I first wrote it, I named it `tProp` to not conflict with `prop` and keep both intact, but as i posted I read the question again, *`Is any way to modify jQuery .prop() function`*, and decided to answer the question asked instead.

Comment: You know as well as I do that lots of people ask for things here that aren't good for them or aren't the right solution to the problem.  I prefer to propose the better solution to the overall problem rather than only answer the literal question.

Answer (score 4):

how about turning it around: checking the property when you fire an event?

```
$(document).on('pseudoInput.refresh',function(event){
    $(event.target).prop('checked',true);
});

$('input').trigger('pseudoInput.refresh');
```

another options is making a plugin for it that checks it and fires the event automatically

Answer (score 1):

Based on @adeneo answer I made this code which is working for me

```
    $.fn.oldProp = $.fn.prop;
    $.fn.prop = function(a, b) {            
        if (a !== undefined && b !== undefined) {
            this.oldProp(a, b);
            if (a.indexOf('checked') > -1) {                    
                this.trigger('pseudoInput.refresh');
            }                
            return this;
        } else if(a !== undefined){
            return this.oldProp(a);
        } else{
            return this;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my earlier suggestion which I think is a conceptually much better idea than changing the meaning of `.prop()`.

```
jQuery.fn.checkAndTrigger = function() {
    return this.prop('checked', true).trigger('pseudoInput.refresh');
};
```

Then, to use it you just do this:

```
objCheckAll.checkAndTrigger();
```

---

Based on your comments, if you're avoiding a conceptually better way to solve a problem because you don't want to use search and replace on some existing code, then you're either not very interested in righting good code or you really need to learn how to use your editing tools to make the search/replace pretty easy.